# Is it possible to chain -ms-filters in CSS?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, filter

Does anyone know of a way to chain the proprietary filter properties in CSS.

For example I have a `div.example` and I want to give it a background gradient and a drop shadow. So I'd like to do something like this:

```
div.example {
  /* gradient */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorstr=#cb141e78,endColorstr=#cb1dde78);
  /* shadow */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropShadow(color=00143c, offX=0, offY=3, positive=true);
}
```

Except this will of course leave only the drop shadow. Anyone know a good workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't this work:

```
div.example {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorstr=#cb141e78,endColorstr=#cb1dde78)
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropShadow(color=00143c, offX=0, offY=3, positive=true);
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I didn't imagine it would be so easy :D